# Checking that one value is selected as yes within three Boolean values

Tags: xml, xsd

I was wondering if it was possible to place a restriction on 3 yes/no elements. I want atleasst one of the three to be selected as a 'yes'

The bpplena values are down below. Any idea on how to place this restriction?

```
<xs:element name="ResponseTime" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="TwelveHour" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
          <xs:element name="SevenDay" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
          <xs:element name="FortyEightHours" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
          <xs:element name="Departure" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:maxLength value="250"/>
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

Comment: Note that `yes` is not among the legal values for `xs:boolean`: `true`, `false`, `1`, and `0`.  Question is nonetheless valid; see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

**If you're using XML Schema 1.1**, you can [specify co-occurrence constraints](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xml11pt2/) via XPath 2.0 using `xs:assert` like this (untested):

```
<xs:element name="ResponseTime" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="TwelveHour" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="SevenDay" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="FortyEightHours" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="Departure" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="250"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:assert test="count((TwelveHour|SevenHour|FortyEightHours)[. = 'true']) gt 0"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

**If you're using XML Schema 1.0**, you cannot express such a constraint in the schema, but you could use [Schematron](http://xml.ascc.net/resource/schematron/) or check it at the application level.